# Alert or Message Box are not popping up after an IF/Else Condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

The code itself is working but my only problem is the alert box. Below is my code where it confirms if a categoryID in a table is the same with the categoryID of the other table. My concern is. My variable `$message` with `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";` does not pop-up before heading into the location. WHat I want is when the two categoryID's does not match. I want to pop-up an alert message (eg. "NO ID MATCHED) before heading into the location `header("Location:addpost.php");`

But when I removed `header("Location:addpost.php");` and let `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";` remain. It pops-up.

Thank you for the help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include "dbconnect.php";
$message = "wrong answer";
if (isset($_GET['categoryID'])) {
    $_SESSION['postCategory']['categoryID'] = $_GET['categoryID'];
}

$que = "SELECT * FROM `post`";
$res = $con->query($que);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['categoryID'] == $_SESSION['postCategory']['categoryID']) {
        header("Location:postCategory.php?categoryID=".$_SESSION['postCategory']['categoryID']);
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        header("Location:addpost.php");
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks to be like you don't have PHP errors enabled. `header("Location:addpost.php");` should throw an error.

Comment: If you're server is telling the page to redirect, there shouldn't be any data that ti should try to show first.  The expectation is that the browser gets the redirect response, and immediately redirects.

Comment: To answer your question `header("Location:addpost.php");` should be the first and only output to the browser, before any JS or HTML, otherwise this should generate error in PHP. This is a header redirect which does not print any data in the browser, it rather tells the browser that the requested page can be found at a different URL

Comment: Is it possible like. A Message box with [OK] button and when I clicked the [OK] button. That's only the time it will redirect it to the `header("Location:addpost.php");` ?

Comment: This would require coding in the browser i.e. client-side like JavaScript. This is not something that you would do with PHP

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to 'addpost.php' using javascript :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('$message');
window.location.href = 'addpost.php';
</script>";
```